# How to clone specific key value pairs in an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects

```
resources=[{name:'x', title:'xx',..},{name:'y',title:'yy',..}..]
```

I am populating my Html tooltip with all the titles of the `resources` array by pushing the individual titles to a new array

```
dialogOkClick(field) {

  this.resources.forEach((res) => {
    if(this.selectedItems.indexOf(res.title) === -1) {
      this.selectedItems.push(res.title);
      this.tooltipText = this.selectedItems.join(', ');
    }
  });
```

}

Pushing the individual items to new array is causing the two arrays to be in consistent. How do I clone all the titles to a new array in one go instead of pushing each item?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a Javascript question rather than an Angular related one...

You can use the `map` function of Arrays in Javascript. The idea is that you return a new value for each element in the original array.

```
let titles = resources.map(obj => obj.title);
```

This way, all the titles in the `resources` array will appear in the `titles` array.

Also, I would suggest you take the `join` call out of the `foreach` loop. You're basically joining all the elements once for every item in the `resources` array.